# Animate a movie along a path in BonsaiJS

Tags: javascript, bonsaijs

I have been building a series of animations using BonsaiJs and really enjoying using the library.

Thinks have been working really well for some keyframe animations, and shape animations.

However I have come a bit unstuck trying to animate a Movie along a curved path. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately moving a `DisplayObject` along a motion path is not supported yet. Would be nice if you could create an issue on [github.com/uxebu/bonsai/](https://github.com/uxebu/bonsai/).